# two structs that refer to each other

Tags: c, struct

How can I have two different structs that refer to each other? One holds a pointer to the other and I also have a forward declaration:

```
struct json_array_t; 

struct json_array_entry_t {
    enum json_type type;                
    union {
        bool                boolean; 
        long long           integer; 
        double              floating; 
        char*               string; 
        struct json_array_t array; 
    }; 
}; 

struct json_array_t {
    struct json_array_entry_t* entries; 
    size_t len, cap;
};
```

I am getting these errors:

```
error: field ‘array’ has incomplete type
   27 |         struct json_array_t array;
```

Comment: To define an actual instance of a structure you need the full definition of the structure. To define a *pointer* to a structure you only need to know the structure tag. So do a forward declaration of the `json_array_entry_t` structure, and then change the order in which you define the structure.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks that worked

Comment: You say "To define a pointer to a structure you only need to know the structure tag". In my experience that is unnecessary. Just declare a pointer_to_some_type and the compiler will reserve space for a pointer and does type checking on assignment. Only once you want dereference the pointer and access its members, must the type fully be known.

Comment: It is highly recommended to change the names of the variables in the union of json_array_entry_t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler needs to know the exact size of `struct json_array_t` to determine how much memory it needs to allocate for the `union` member inside of the structure `json_array_entry_t` and with that how much memory it needs to allocate for an object of the structure `json_array_entry_t` in whole.

A simple forward declaration of `struct json_array_t`, as you did, is not sufficient in this case.

Place the definition of `struct json_array_t`

```
struct json_array_t {
    struct json_array_entry_t* entries; 
    size_t len, cap;
};
```

before the definition of `struct json_array_entry_t`. In this way the compiler knows the size of the structure `json_array_t` and you can also spare the forward declaration of it.

Since `entries` is only a pointer you don't need a forward-declaration for `json_array_entry_t`.

---

```
struct json_array_t {
    struct json_array_entry_t* entries; 
    size_t len, cap;
};

struct json_array_entry_t {
    enum json_type type;                
    union {
        bool                boolean; 
        long long           integer; 
        double              floating; 
        char*               string; 
        struct json_array_t array; 
    }; 
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You must first define `struct json_array_t` and then `struct json_array_entry_t`.

When you now define in `struct json_array_entry_t` an occurrence of `json_array_t` it and all its members are fully known to the compiler.

Comment: _... and all its members **(and its size)** are fully known to the compiler._

Comment: @DavidRanieri, of course. That's implied by "fully known". Still good to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You can define `json_array_entry_t` before `json_array_t` since you will just use it as a pointer inside `json_array_t`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// just an example
enum json_type {
  _BOOL, _INT, _DOUBLE, _STRING, _ARRAY
};

struct json_array_entry_t;

struct json_array_t {
  struct json_array_entry_t* entries; 
  size_t len, cap;
};

struct json_array_entry_t {
  enum json_type type;                
  union {
    bool                boolean; 
    long long           integer; 
    double              floating; 
    char*               string; 
    struct json_array_t array; 
  }; 
}; 

int main() {
  // some coding
  return 0;
}
```